# Error en el if de timeout

Tags: python

Hola alguien me ayude miren hice un key logger de un video y me sale error en la if de timeout alguien me ayuda?, no se por que sale ese error hice todo el codigo bien. Espero que alguien me ayude

Error:

```
9
   if time.time() > timeout
                           
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Solo pongo la parte del error

Code:

```
import time, datetime

wait_seconds = 60
timeout = time.time() + wait_seconds
file_log = 'C:\\secret\\dat.txt'

def TimeOut():
    if time.time() > timeout
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: faltan los dos puntos al final en el if

Comment: graciasssssssss

Comment: Comprobado el comentario de @SalvadorMellado, tan solo es necesario agregar "dos puntos" `:` al final de la línea  8 `if time.time() > timeout` => `if time.time() > timeout:`

Answer (score 1):

**Te falta un doble punto al final de tu sentencia if**

Te recomiendo que entres al siguiente enlace para que veas cual es la sitaxis correcta.

https://www.programaenpython.com/fundamentos/sentencias-condicionales-en-python/

Tu codigo:

```
import time, datetime

wait_seconds = 60
timeout = time.time() + wait_seconds
file_log = 'C:\\secret\\dat.txt'

def TimeOut():
    if time.time() > timeout:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```